# strict ordering a Set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

Given:
$(A,<)$ is a strictly ordered set and $b \notin A$.

Define:
a relation $\prec$ in $ B = A \bigcup \{b\} $ as:
$x\prec y $ if and only if $(x,y \in A \text{ and } x<y)$ or $(x \in A \text{ and } y=b)$

Show that $\prec $ is a strict ordering of $B \text{ and } \prec \bigcap A^{2} =<$.

I know that I need to show the relation is asymmetric and transitive.

Here is what I have :

Asymmetric:
let $x \prec y $ then $ x < y \text{ OR } x \in A \text{ and } y = b$

if $x<y$ then $y \not< x$ since $<$ is a strict order.

if $x \in A \text{ and } y=B$ then $y \not\prec x \text{ since } y \notin A \text{ and } x\not= b$

therefore $\prec$ is asymmetric.

Transitive:
I know how to show it is transitive if $x, y, z \in A$ as I would just fall back on the given that $<$ is a strict order.

However I don't know how to show it if $y=b$.

Comment: I think you probably mean that $\prec \bigcap A^{2} = <$ rather than $\bigcup$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Note that there is no element $z$ such that $b\prec z$.